# Need help fixing difficulty selection for guessing game in java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

I need help making my guessing game give you the option to choose which difficulty, can someone fix my code and repost it because I'm kinda lost right now!

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean play = true;
    String input1;

    while(play == true){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int counter = 0;
        int guess = -1;
        int dif = 0;
        int easy = rand.nextInt(10) + 1, med = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1, hard = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1; 

        System.out.println("Difficulty Select");
        System.out.println("=================");
        System.out.print("1) Easy   2) Medium   3) Hard     :");
        dif = input.nextInt();

        switch (dif)
        {
            case 1:
                if (dif == 1)
                    System.out.println ("Random number between 1 and 10 selected." + easy);
                else if (dif == 3)
                    System.out.println ("Random number between 1 and 10000 selected.");
            break;


        }
        while (guess != med)
        {
            System.out.print ("|" + med + "|" + "Random number between 1 and 1000 selected.");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            counter = counter + 1;

            if (guess == med)
                System.out.println ("YOU WIN MOFO!");
            else if (guess < med)
                System.out.println ("You're to cold!");
            else if (guess > med)
                System.out.println ("You're to hot!");
        }

        System.out.println ("It took you " + counter + " guess(es) to get it correct"); 
        System.out.print ("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ");
        input1 = input.nextLine();  // absorb enter key from integer
        input1 = input.nextLine();

        if (input1.equals("y"))
           play = true;
        else
           play = false;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question should always include what your program is supposed to do and what it currently does. The users on here will be far less willing to help you if they have to guess all that.

Comment: If it's a crash, a stacktrace would help

Comment: *"can someone fix my code and repost it because I'm kinda lost right now!"*  SO is not a 'finish my homework' service.  Ask a more specific question, because this one is liable to be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finishing someones homework.

Answer (score 2):

Do not combine a `switch` and an `if` for the same purpose (and put them inside each other). Pick one. Both are fine here.

In your construction here:

```
switch (dif)
{
    case 1:
        if (dif == 3) ...

}
```

The if can never be true, since you put it in the `case 1` block. Obviously, `dif` can't be both 1 and 3 at the same time.